# How can I get my JSP to locate my CSS file within Spring MVC?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am relatively new to web development, and I am trying to develop a web application using Spring MVC 3.0.5 on WebLogic 10.3.4.

I'd like my JSPs to use external CSS files.  For example, I have a JSP file with the following:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<LINK href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/ptostyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<title>Register</title>
</head>
```

Unfortunately, the CSS file doesn't seem to get loaded.  I have tried putting it in various places.  The current directory structure looks like:

[image]

Relevant portions of my web.xml include:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>WebContent/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Any suggestions, including debugging strategies would be much appreciated!

Comment: The WebLogic-Tag is irrelevant as long as you are not doing any appserver-specific stuff

Comment: I agree, Sean.  However, in reading some related posts, I saw some solutions that were specific to Tomcat (for example).  While I prefer a generic solution, I'd rather have an appserver-specific solution to no solution at all.  Since the solution I stumbled across seems to be independent of weblogic, removing the tag is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to access my CSS by doing the following:

1. I moved my resources folder directly under WebContent, as suggested
   by Sean
2. I commented out the portions of web.xml that involved the
   ResourceServlet.
3. I added the following line to spring-context.xml

   ```
   <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   ```

This [article](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-102166.html) discusses some other issues and workarounds that may be applicable to a WebLogic deployment.  There appears to be a [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8461) in the implementation of Spring 3.0.5 that can cause problems delivering static resources.

Comment: This is the Spring 3.1.x way to do it. The `Resource Servlet` method is the way we did it prior to version 3.04.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing under the WEB-INF folder is publicly available. When browsers request your CSS file, they can not see inside the WEB-INF folder.

Try putting your resources/css folder under WebContent.

Folder structure would be

```
WebContent
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
      ...
   resources
      css
        ptostyles.css
```